# VB: create comma separated string from array

Tags: vba

I am trying to convert a list of array values to a comma separated string, with single quotes.

my array name is:

```
info.arr_fonts(
               (0)times
               (1)verdana
               (2)arial
               (3)tahoma
               (4)helvetica
              ) - values are dynamic, can be +/-.
enter code here
```

I would like to write them into a string variable like:

```
"times, verdana, arial, tahoma, helvetica"
```

can someone show me how this can be done? I tried something simple like:

```
Dim strFonts As String
strFonts = Join(info.FontArray, ",")
```

But that does not add the single quotes around each word.

**UPDATE**

```
Dim arrFontNames As Variant
Dim strFonts As String
Dim lCtr As Long

arrFontNames = Array("Doremi", "Times-Roman", "Helvetica", "Jivetalk", "Jive")

strFonts = Join(arrFontNames, ",")
```

content of strFonts:

```
"Doremi,Times-Roman,Helvetica,Jivetalk,Jive"
```

I need to pass the strFonts as a parameter to a stored procedure. The stored procedure needs to receive it lie this:

```
'Doremi,Times-Roman,Helvetica,Jivetalk,Jive'
```

Will the double quotes from VBA convert to single quotes once it executes the stored procedure, or do I need to do some string manipulation still?

Comment: Loop through each element and add the quotes. `Join` Won't help here.

Comment: Which is it?  VBA or VB6?

Comment: vba, I just removed vb6.

Comment: `strFonts = """('" & Join(info.FontArray, "','") & "')"""`

Comment: for: strFonts = ""("'" & Join(info.FontArray, "','") & "')""" - compiler return expected end of statement.

Comment: @erasmocarlos I had a typo. I edited the comment. Refresh your screen and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the quotes by loop.

```
Sub test()

    Dim lCtr As Long

    For lCtr = LBound(info.FontArray) To UBound(info.FontArray)
        info.FontArray(lCtr) = "'" & info.FontArray(lCtr) & "'"
    Next

    strFonts = Join(info.FontArray, ",")

End Sub
```

As per your edit to the question. for a single param in stored proc all you need to do is 
`strFonts = "'" & Join(info.FontArray, ",") & "'"`

Comment: what is this line doing?:  info.FontArray(lCtr) = "'" & info.FontArray(lCtr) & "'"

Comment: adding quotes and updating the array element.

Comment: I see every loop goes through each element in the array, but rather than building a string, it replaces it. and in the end it contains the same as it originally came: "Doremi,Times-Roman,Helvetica,Jivetalk,Jive"

Comment: No, not possible. Until and unless you missed something, as per my answer `strFont` will have quotes around the array elements.

Comment: You were right, I was missing something. I got the code to work, can you please see the update?

Comment: You still need to add single quotes. SQL will reject double quotes for string parameters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117463/discussion-between-cyboashu-and-erasmo-carlos).